# Standard form type for editing mutlivalue? (Symfony CMF PHPCR)

Tags: sonata-admin, symfony-cmf, doctrine-phpcr

I'm using Sonata Admin as a backend. I have within PHPCR Document field that is multivalued (i.e. in PHP an array of strings). Now I'd like to add/remove elements from it within Sonata admin. Which type should I use? Tried collection, but I get nothing in admin; when I try sonata_type_collection admin expects from me admin code (I guess another admin), which is not the case.

Which form type should I use for a Document's field like the one below?

```
/**
 * @PHPCR\String(nullable=true, multivalue=true)
 */
protected $tags;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a chapter on [form types for PHPCR-ODM](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cmf/bundles/phpcr_odm/forms.html) in the cmf documentation. There is [BurgovKeyValueBundle](https://github.com/Burgov/KeyValueFormBundle) that allows you to edit associative arrays. For non-associative multivalue fields, i think you just need to use the [array](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/doctrine-orm-admin/master/doc/reference/form_field_definition.html#types-available) type of sonata admin.

Comment: Thanks. However, I have checked before all of them, including the PHPCR-ODM docs mentioned. With 'array' (this is from ORM doc) type I get the Could not load type "array" msg. Maybe ODM doesn't accept all ORM types?

 I need here non-associative array (I don't need additional "dictionary-like" info for tags here, I guess).

Comment: Then I don't know. Best open an issue on https://github.com/doctrine/phpcr-odm-documentation